# How to echo a $_GET safely?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

Doesn't look very safe to me.. What is our best option to show an `GET` element?

Something like a `preg_replace` on all the special characters, or `htmlspecialchars`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what you are doing to do with **`$_GET['id'];`**

If you are looking to insert it into database , Just make use of **`Prepared Statements`**. [That suffices]

If you just want to display it on your HTML page, make use of this code.

```
<?php
    echo htmlentities($_GET['id']);
?>
```

Comment: `htmlentities()` does more escaping than necessary (as opposed to `htmlspecialchars()`).

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
    echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

htmlspecialchars() if it is a string, or cast  to the appropriate type if it is numeric (intval(), or (int) etc.), for example:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
//or
echo (int)$_GET['id'];
```

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is sufficient with numeric values, too.

Comment: It's sufficient, but if it's supposed to be an int then casting to an int will at least give you 0 if there is text or other garbage.

Answer (score 2):

If it's `id`, I think it should be numeric - then `echo intval($_GET['id']);`

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough:

```
htmlspecialchars($_GET['id'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```